# Executing shell script from php opens the file on Windows (Xampp)

Tags: php, bash, shell, laravel, xampp

I'm trying to run a script from my PHP file. When I run the script, it just opens my notepad instead of executing the file.
I have given my folder read and write permissions, tried to run via SSH (because I work with Vagrant) and via cmd. But nothing seems to work. I think my code is correct, which you can find bellow:

```
$output = shell_exec(getcwd()."/scripts/row.sh 2>&1");
```

Someone who can help me out?

Comment: I have next to no experience with MS-Windows, but are you sure that the unix typical `2>&1` can be used under that system? Also might be worth exploring what "default application" is registered inside the system to handle "*.sh" files.

Comment: Yes, I think so. the `2>&1` seemed to work the last time I checked. Without the `2>&1` it opens a notepad aswell. I'll have a look at the windows .sh handler

Comment: `2>&1` works with both windows (cmd) & linux (*sh)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because your `OPEN WITH` for `.sh` files is set to `notepad`.

Check below output:

```
my_prompt> assoc .sh
.sh=sh_auto_file
    ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ <~~~~~~ Remember this name

my_prompt> ftype sh_auto_file <~~~~~~~~~~Use it here
sh_auto_file=%SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE %1
```

You can change the association with:

```
my_prompt> ftype sh_auto_file=c:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe %1 %*
```

(Change the path for bash.exe as per your setup...)

For more details, run commands `assoc /?` & `ftype /?` on `cmd.exe`. (`/?` is typical equivalent of `-h` or `--help` in Linux commands...)

Also, for more advanced users, check in registry for `HKCR\.sh` & `HKCR\sh_auto_file`. 
You can use `regedit` for it.

Comment: Thenks. You got me on the right track. Still trying to get it to work, but now I know where to look!